# Associated Legendre Polynomials - unclear step in the derivation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

Hello, I'm finding it hard to understand the last equation. How is it a result of differentiating m times the equation above it? The source is https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Associated_Legendre_Function.